# dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for port 53: Address already in use

Tags: socket, internal-dns, dnsmasq

I got this error when i done the setup dnsmasq.

```
ashokkrishna@krishna:~$ sudo dnsmasq

dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for port 53: Address already in use


ashokkrishna@krishna:~$ netstat -lpn | grep :53
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::53755                :::*                    LISTEN      -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                -               
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                -
```

so how to solve this or how to stop those sockets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
netstat -tupln
```

you will get result like this:

```
tcp   0  0 :::80   :::*      LISTEN    713/httpd
```

take the pid for the process that listening on th port 53 and kill it with this command

```
kill -9 pid
```

Comment: actually the process is nsd i cannot kill that process

Comment: that is again coming into existence

Comment: I thought you wanna run another DNS server and you wanna stop the first one

Comment: no i havent any dns servers my server is itself a dns server

Comment: This is only a temporary solution. For a permanent solution please consider my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I just spent hours trying to resolve this issue in a reasonable manner without any major system modifications.

Stop dnsmasq from auto starting.

`servicectl disable dnsmasq`

Create file `/etc/rc.local` or `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` depending on distro.

Set perms `chmod +x /etc/rc.local`

Edit file:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
service systemd-resolved stop
service dnsmasq start
```

Simply stopping systemd-resolved then starting dnsmasq after full boot works perfect, at least on Mint. I can't speak on other distros.

Comment: systemd-resolved is part of the systemd init system and therefore you would use the appropriate commands;
sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved

Answer (score 0):

Check for port usage with;

```
lsof -i -n -P
```

In my case, systemd-resolved was blocking port 53 from use as below:

```
systemd-r  640 systemd-resolve   12u  IPv4  22295      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.53:53
systemd-r  640 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  22296      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
```

Simply disable systemd-resolved before enabling dnsmasq;

```
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved --now
sudo systemctl enable dnsmasq --now
```